# Java - Unparseable date exception

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a date object which has date in the format: `2015-09-21 10:42:48:000`
I want it to be displayed on the UI in this format.`21-Sep-2015 10:42:48`

The code I am using is not working and throws this:

> Unparseable date exception: Unparseable date: "2015-09-21 10:42:48"

Here is the actual code:

```
 String createdOn=f.getCreatedOn().toString();//f.getCreatedOn() returns a date object
 SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 Date date=format.parse(createdOn.substring(0,createdOn.length()-3));
 log.debug(">>>>>>date now is: "+date);
 model.addAttribute("date", date);
 model.addAttribute("info", messages);
 SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 format1.format(date);
 log.debug(">>>>>>date now is again: "+date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unparseable date exception: Unparseable date: "2015-09-21 10:42:48"

Since your input date format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. But you are trying parsing with `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` format.

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//change input date format here
Date date=format.parse("2015-09-21 10:42:48:000");
//Date date=format.parse(createdOn);//Here no need of subtracting 000 from your date
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format1.format(date));
```

[SimpleDateFormat doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your input date format is different.

```
String createdOn="2015-09-21 10:42:48:000";
        SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date=format.parse(createdOn.substring(0,createdOn.length()-4));
        System.out.println(">>>>>>date now is: "+date);

        SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        format1.format(date);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>date now is again: "+date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong format to display and parse.

```
// We will use this for parsing a string that represents a date with the format declared below. If you try to parse a date string with a different format, you will get an exception like you did   
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

// This is for the way we want it to be displayed
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// Parse the date string
Date date = parseFormat.parse("2015-09-21 10:42:48:000");

// Format the date with the display format
String displayDate = displayFormat.format(date);

System.out.println(">>>>>>date now is: " + displayDate);
```